PNG insert to Excel and convert Base64
I have a lot of information, such as company, employee name, Transportation, photo，but I want to convert the photo to base64。I don't know VBA very well. I have looked for several examples, but they all failed.This file will be uploaded on the web page later, and I will convert Base64 to image in the background.
Or is there a better way?

Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. It's not at all clear what you are trying to do, how or why. Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sorry，I just want to show photo at excel when I input a text(base64) 。
